# How to give double slash in url of flask api

Tags: python, linux, flask, url-parameters, slash

I need to pass a string to an api which is a filepath to process the file and return the output. Example: url is

```
122.23.198.198:5000/D:/FILES/meta.pdf
```

The issue here is that the path of the file in the linux machine is /D:/FILES/meta.pdf. The problem is with the slash before D: How do I escape/add double slashes in my flask api route. I am getting a file not found error presently.

Reference code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)   
class ectdtext(Resource):
    def get(self, result):
        return {'data': ectd.convert(result)}

#api.add_resource(ectdtext, '/ectd/<result>')
#categorie

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def get_dir(path):
    categories = convert(path)
    return categories

#@app.route('/get_dir/<path>')
#def get_dir(path):
#    return path

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

Comment: Do you really need to do it like that, or can it be a parameter like it typically would be? `122.23.198.198:5000/?path=%2fD:%2fFILES%2fmeta.pdf`

Comment: It can be how I showed or the pattern you have given. It has to process the file which is sent after 5000/ and return the category of that file. If I pass something like what you have sent in the url,it's not working now. How can I configure my route to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, you want to convent Linux style path to Windows style, then you can use `os.path.abspath`:

```py
>>> os.path.abspath('/D:/FILES/meta.pdf')
'D:\\FILES\\meta.pdf'
```

You will need to change your code into this:

```py
import os  # <--

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def get_dir(path):
    categories = os.path.abspath(path)  # <--
    return categories
```

However, I'd recommend to accept relative URL in view function, then combine it with the base path, for example:

```py
import os

basedir = 'the base dir that stores the upload files'

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def get_dir(path):
    categories = os.path.join(basedir, path)
    return categories
```

Or you maybe need to filter the path for safe consideration:

```py
>>> from werkzeug import secure_filename
>>> secure_filename('the path')
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your first method with abspath but what it is doing is taking the path of the location of my python file with the location of the pdf file and saying file not found error. However if I copy the pdf file to the location of my python script, it's working.